# Is it possible to filter issues for a specific version by name instead of using query_id?

Tags: redmine

Currently I can filter Redmine query results by project with the following URL:

https://redmine-domain.co.uk/projects/**[redmine_project_name]**/issues?query_id=153

For this query I would have to know the query_id number. Instead what I'd like to be able to do is specify the version name like this:

https://redmine-domain.co.uk/projects/[redmine_project_name]/**version/[current_release_version]**

This way I would be able to know the correct query link without having to go in to Redmine to get the specific query_id.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

According this (str 189 from query_helper.rb):

```
@query = IssueQuery.where(cond).find(params[:query_id])
```

I think it is impossible.